# Python argument to select a specific window

Tags: python, pynput

I'm trying to code a Discord bot, that when you type `!start` it starts a process on my computer and when you type `!stop` it stops the server, but here's the deal, when you type the command `!stop` it doesn't write my code in a cmd but wherever your cursor is selected to write.

This is very complicated to explain but in summary I just want to know if there is a specific argument that can change which window is selected.

I'm a newbie to python, so please explain in detail.
I'm using `pynput` to have the ability to have control of my keyboard to stop my server.

Here's the code, I just need to be able to execute this only in a cmd even if I'm in chrome.

```
import os
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller

keyboard = Controller()


time.sleep(10)
keyboard.type("stop")
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)

time.sleep(10)

keyboard.type("a")
time.sleep(10)

keyboard.type("exit")
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your operating system is Windows, you can use [PyGetWindow](https://github.com/asweigart/pygetwindow) to switch windows.

```
import pygetwindow as gw

print(gw.getAllTitles())
handle = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Notepad')[0]
handle.activate()
handle.maximize()
```